# How to restore removed commits from remote repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

I accidentally removed commits from my current branch on the remote by force push from my local machine. The problem is all the posts I looked told to use `git reflogs` to find the hash but they were not there because these commits were added directly to `Azure DevOps` repo using the user interface(website). Now I can see commit hashes in pushes section of `Azure DevOps` but after doing a `git fetch`, when I try `git reset --hard <commit_id>` I get `fatal: Could not parse object 'a0c348c837a039db553c9c83bb2a1ec97d3b5711'` for example. So is there a way to return these? Unfortunately there were no local machines with the removed commits.

Comment: I hope you will be able to recover but today you will learn `--force-with-lease`...

Comment: @Philippe yep I learned it right now! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can browse to the commit in Azure DevOps Repos then you will be able to create a tag or branch on the commit for you to fetch.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked at changes and committed them again manually but I tested your answer. Create tag did not work on itself and after doing `git fetch` it did not appear but I created a branch and then I was able to `cherry-pick` from it.

Comment: To fetch a tag you have to ask nicely; `git fetch --tags`.